# Puppeteer - Click div not working

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm able to login, but i need to click on a div that has no id and i cant figure out how to do it

This is html element. Onclick event (devtool properties) is on the div that has the route (class route-redirect-box)

How can i click this link to go to "listachamados" page?

Page html:

```
<div class="menu-lateral-contraido-sub-container" title="Lista de Chamados" draggable="true" style="opacity: 1;">

<div to="/main/listachamado/" class="route-redirect-box"><div class="menu-lateral-item-contraido-container cor-tema-topo-fundo ">

<div class="menu-lateral-item-contraido-icon"><i class="ellevo-icons">lista_chamado</i></div></div></div></div>

<div class="menu-lateral-item-contraido-icon"><i class="ellevo-icons">lista_chamado</i></div>
<i class="ellevo-icons">lista_chamado</i>
```

My code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let scrape = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://notreal.br/', {waitUntil: 'load'});
    console.log(page.url());

    const SELETOR_USUARIO = '#usuario';
    const SELETOR_SENHA = '#senha';
    const usuario = 'username';
    const senha = 'password';


    await page.type(SELETOR_USUARIO, usuario);
    await page.type(SELETOR_SENHA, senha);
    //await page.waitForNavigation();


    console.log(page.url());
    await Promise.all([
        page.click('#login'),
        page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })

        //page.click('.menu-lateral-item-contraido-container cor-tema-topo-fundo'),

    ]);

    await Permise.all([
      page.waitFor('load'),
      await page.evaluate(() => {
          let lista = document.getElementsByClassName('div.route-redirect-box')
          lista.click()
          //page.click(lista)
      })
    ]);

    //browser.close();
};

scrape().then((value) => {
    console.log(value); 
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You misspelled `Permise.all`. It should be [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

But you might not need to use `Promise.all` because you can just simply [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) the Puppeteer methods that you called.

Additionally, since the [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) event is attached to the `.route-redirect-box` element, you can use [`page.click()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options) or [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to click the element:

```
await page.click('.route-redirect-box');

await page.evaluate(() => {
  document.querySelector('.route-redirect-box').click();
});
```

Or, since you seem to know the URL of the page you are trying to redirect to, you could just use another [`page.goto()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options) to navigate manually:

```
await page.goto('https://example.com/main/listachamado/');
```

Another alternative solution would be, if you know the function that is going to be executed [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick), you can just execute the function itself within [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args):

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  function_to_be_executed_onclick();
});
```

Comment: page.click and page.evaluet does not work. and page.goto just log off. weird, causa if i try to do this manually i stay logged

Comment: @tramada Is there more than one element with `.route-redirect-box`?