# Puppeteer page.click works, but page.evaluate + document click doesn't work

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I've seen so many posts (for example, see [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2526) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51774674/puppeteer-click-div-not-working)), saying that I could click on something via the following code,

```js
await page.click('.route-redirect-box');   // via Puppeteer page.click

await page.evaluate((css_selector) => {
  document.querySelector(css_selector).click();  // or via page.evaluate
}, css);
```

However, as I tested on some websites, looks like `page.click` always works, but `page.evaluate` doesn't, using `headless: false` mode.

For example, this [website](https://www.allbeauty.com/gb/en/brands/burberry?page=1) page, I tried to click on something as follows,

```js
var css = '#searchPaginationTop > nav > a:nth-child(5)';
await page.evaluate((css_selector) => { document.querySelector(css_selector).click();}, css);
```

nothing happened at all, but if I use `page.click`, it worked as expected.

I'm thinking that, the element I wanted to click is not a normal *clickable* element, since the html code for that element is as follows,

```html
<a class="svg" data-goto-page="3" data-total-pages="3" data-ga="event" data-ga-category="Brands at allbeauty-Burberry-Pagination" data-ga-action="Brands at allbeauty-Burberry-Pagination-Next-Touch" data-ga-label="Brands at allbeauty-Burberry-Pagination-Next-Link">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 21.9 38.7" alt="Next Page" title="Next Page ">
        <use xlink:href="#icon-ab-arrow-right">
        </use>
    </svg>
</a>
```

Could it be because this element is some `data-ga` stuff, so `page.evaluate` cannot click on it?

Comment: To me, https://www.allbeauty.com/gb/en/brands/burberry?page=1 shows no children of `#searchPaginationTop`.

I could imagine, that it would be injected dynamically, i.e. you'll need to wait for the respective JavaScript to run.

Comment: @Ryuno-Ki, the css is copied via Chrome inspect tools, I'm not sure if this is injected dynamically. So how could I wait for the respective JS to run? Could you please show some code examples in an answer?

Comment: That a doesn't have an href or an onClick so unless there's some other event listener, nothing will happen when you click it.

Comment: @pguardiario, you're right, there is no `href`, and I guess there should exists some event listeners, but I just couldn't find it. So `page.evaluate` + `document.click` cannot trigger that event listener? Could you please give me more pointers?

Comment: *but if I use `page.click`, it worked as expected* what do you mean by *worked as expected*? How do you tell it worked and what the behavior was?

Comment: @ChristosLytras, I use `headless=false` mode, so I could see if the element is really clicked when that code is executed.

Comment: @avocado this is not related to how `puppeteer` works. If you open the page to the browser and open dev tools console and execute `document.querySelector('#searchPaginationTop > nav > a:nth-child(5)').click()` nothing will happen either. This is because this is not a direct link but the JS application handles the mouse events. It can even register a global window event to catch all `mousedown`/`click` events.

Comment: @ChristosLytras, I see, so if that's the case, any workaround to click via `page.evaluate`?

Comment: It uses [Newrelic platform](https://newrelic.com/platform). They have a big [github account](https://github.com/newrelic). @avocado why do you want to do the click using javascript? What's wrong with puppeteer click method? To do that in browser JS, you'll either have to reverse the JS code and see how the mouse event is registered/handled (or even locate that to the github source code) or randomly try to experiment with [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) and [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent).

Comment: @ChristosLytras, I see, sounds complicated, then I'll keep puppeteer click then, thanks so much for providing such detailed clues :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Short answer

- `page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('SELECTOR').click());` just fires the `click` event
- `page.click('SELECTOR')` tries to mimic human behavior when clicking

### Explanation

Let's check the documentation for both methods to really understand what is happening.

#### `page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('SELECTOR').click());`

Let's see what the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) says:

> [...] It fires the element's click event.

That's all it does. It *just* fires the `click` event, so that all handlers listening to that click event of the element are called. This means, it does not care if the element is outside of the current viewport. The element might even be hidden (via CSS) and the `click` event would still fire.

Let's compare that to the "puppeteer-way":

#### `page.click`

The part of the [puppeteer documentation](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options) regarding `page.click`:

> This method fetches an element with `selector`, scrolls it into view if needed, and then uses [`page.mouse`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#pagemouse) to click in the center of the element. [...]

That means, that puppeteer mimics human behavior here. First, the element is scrolled into view, then the mouse is moved on top of the element (triggering any other events like `mouseover`, `mouseenter`, etc. on the way). Finally, the button is clicked by simulation a mouse (see the corresponding [`Mouse`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/b9240b1664b86a3573b23ccee6bb0c2b35d9ac9b/lib/Input.js#L184) class in the puppeteer code). This also triggers any related events (like `mousedown`).

Complex UI libraries might not like it, when you trigger JavaScript events on your own. Keep in mind, they are often optimized for human interaction, not for interaction with bots. That means, the UI library might listen to the `mousedown` or `mouseenter` event (as an example) instead of directly listening to the `click` event.

### Behaving "human-like"

When interacting with an unknown website, it is best to try to behave as human as possible. Even pages that do not have any specific "anti-bot" measures, might use frameworks that expect a specific flow of events.

By the way, you are not the only one having this problem. Check out these questions for similar problems:

- [Click event not triggering in an Angular application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55910796/5627599)
- [Setting `value` of input field does not work (also Angular)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55560220/5627599)

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation, :-)

Answer (score 4):

From what I can tell, the content seem to be injected dynamically.
That means, by using [waitForSelector](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.1.1&show=api-pagewaitforselectorselector-options) of Puppeteer, you can wait for it to happen before continuing. Something along these lines should do (can't replicate it myself, since I don't know know how to trigger the update of the nav):

```
await page.click('.route-redirect-box');
const css = '#searchPaginationTop > nav > a:nth-child(5)';
await page.waitForSelector(css);
await page.evaluate((css_selector) => { document.querySelector(css_selector).click();}, css);
```

Comment: I added `waitForSelector`, but still `evaluate` doesn't work.

Comment: Could you add some instructions on how to get into a state, that `#searchPaginationTop` gets populated? Otherwise I can't help you.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to do that yet, but I guess the issue here could be what @pguardiario said in the comment.